Is this the normal speed of A100 in google colab or are there any mistakes in my code?
I am trying to train a net to classify CIFAR-100 dataset. However, It takes a long time using my Nvidia RTX3060. Therefore, I buy the google calab pro and use A100 to train my code, but it seemed that it is only about 12.5% faster than my 3060. Is this the normal speed of A100? Or are there more reasons?
Here is the google colab using A100:
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
1it [00:00,  4.87it/s]
2it [00:00,  6.53it/s]
3it [00:00,  7.35it/s]
4it [00:00,  7.74it/s]
5it [00:00,  7.92it/s]
6it [00:00,  8.04it/s]
7it [00:00,  8.12it/s]
8it [00:01,  7.91it/s]
9it [00:01,  7.95it/s]
10it [00:01,  7.89it/s]
11it [00:01,  8.02it/s]
12it [00:01,  8.18it/s]
13it [00:01,  8.16it/s]
14it [00:01,  8.23it/s]
15it [00:01,  8.32it/s]
16it [00:02,  8.31it/s]
17it [00:02,  8.23it/s]
18it [00:02,  8.27it/s]
19it [00:02,  8.03it/s]
20it [00:02,  8.17it/s]
21it [00:02,  8.30it/s]
22it [00:02,  8.35it/s]
23it [00:02,  8.44it/s]
24it [00:02,  8.48it/s]
25it [00:03,  8.21it/s]
26it [00:03,  8.26it/s]
27it [00:03,  8.33it/s]
28it [00:03,  8.37it/s]
29it [00:03,  8.50it/s]
30it [00:03,  8.29it/s]
31it [00:03,  8.36it/s]
32it [00:03,  8.47it/s]
33it [00:04,  8.44it/s]
34it [00:04,  8.20it/s]
35it [00:04,  8.30it/s]
36it [00:04,  8.29it/s]
37it [00:04,  8.12it/s]
38it [00:04,  7.98it/s]
39it [00:04,  8.05it/s]
40it [00:04,  8.05it/s]
41it [00:05,  8.08it/s]
42it [00:05,  8.10it/s]
43it [00:05,  8.10it/s]
44it [00:05,  8.22it/s]
45it [00:05,  8.32it/s]
46it [00:05,  8.34it/s]
47it [00:05,  8.10it/s]
48it [00:05,  8.24it/s]
49it [00:06,  8.36it/s]
50it [00:06,  8.44it/s]
51it [00:06,  8.41it/s]
52it [00:06,  8.47it/s]
53it [00:06,  8.40it/s]
54it [00:06,  8.36it/s]
55it [00:06,  8.30it/s]
56it [00:06,  8.37it/s]
57it [00:06,  8.44it/s]
58it [00:07,  8.41it/s]
59it [00:07,  8.46it/s]
60it [00:07,  8.47it/s]
61it [00:07,  8.46it/s]
62it [00:07,  8.46it/s]
63it [00:07,  8.36it/s]
64it [00:07,  8.39it/s]
65it [00:07,  8.38it/s]
66it [00:08,  8.38it/s]
67it [00:08,  8.36it/s]
68it [00:08,  8.32it/s]
69it [00:08,  8.34it/s]
70it [00:08,  8.16it/s]

Here is my RTX3060
cuda:0
  0%|          | 0/100 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
1it [00:03,  3.30s/it]
2it [00:03,  1.44s/it]
3it [00:03,  1.18it/s]
4it [00:03,  1.75it/s]
5it [00:03,  2.40it/s]
6it [00:04,  3.09it/s]
7it [00:04,  3.78it/s]
8it [00:04,  4.45it/s]
9it [00:04,  5.09it/s]
10it [00:04,  5.68it/s]
11it [00:04,  6.06it/s]
12it [00:04,  6.34it/s]
13it [00:04,  6.57it/s]
14it [00:05,  6.74it/s]
15it [00:05,  6.90it/s]
16it [00:05,  6.90it/s]
17it [00:05,  6.90it/s]
18it [00:05,  7.01it/s]
19it [00:05,  7.08it/s]
20it [00:05,  7.21it/s]
21it [00:06,  7.14it/s]
22it [00:06,  7.08it/s]
23it [00:06,  7.02it/s]
24it [00:06,  6.99it/s]
25it [00:06,  7.02it/s]
26it [00:06,  7.02it/s]
27it [00:06,  7.08it/s]
28it [00:07,  7.20it/s]
29it [00:07,  7.15it/s]
30it [00:07,  7.12it/s]
31it [00:07,  7.05it/s]
32it [00:07,  7.07it/s]
33it [00:07,  7.08it/s]
34it [00:07,  7.01it/s]
35it [00:08,  7.08it/s]
36it [00:08,  7.16it/s]
37it [00:08,  7.04it/s]
38it [00:08,  7.04it/s]
39it [00:08,  7.15it/s]
40it [00:08,  7.14it/s]
41it [00:08,  7.03it/s]
42it [00:09,  7.11it/s]
43it [00:09,  7.15it/s]
44it [00:09,  7.15it/s]
45it [00:09,  7.20it/s]
46it [00:09,  7.12it/s]
47it [00:09,  6.99it/s]
48it [00:09,  6.98it/s]
49it [00:10,  7.03it/s]
50it [00:10,  7.08it/s]
51it [00:10,  6.93it/s]
52it [00:10,  6.96it/s]
53it [00:10,  6.88it/s]
54it [00:10,  6.98it/s]
55it [00:10,  6.99it/s]
56it [00:11,  7.03it/s]
57it [00:11,  6.98it/s]
58it [00:11,  7.01it/s]
59it [00:11,  7.07it/s]
60it [00:11,  7.17it/s]
61it [00:11,  7.17it/s]
62it [00:11,  7.19it/s]
63it [00:12,  7.21it/s]
64it [00:12,  7.21it/s]
65it [00:12,  7.21it/s]
66it [00:12,  7.29it/s]
67it [00:12,  7.28it/s]
68it [00:12,  7.25it/s]
69it [00:12,  7.17it/s]
70it [00:13,  7.21it/s]
71it [00:13,  7.23it/s]
72it [00:13,  7.27it/s]
73it [00:13,  5.42it/s]

Here is my code
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from einops import rearrange


class upanets(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, block, num_blocks, filter_nums, num_classes=100, img=32):

        super(upanets, self).__init__()

        self.in_planes = filter_nums
        self.filters = filter_nums
        w = 2

        self.root = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, int(self.in_planes * w), kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(int(self.in_planes * w)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(int(self.in_planes * w), self.in_planes * 1, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(self.in_planes),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )
        self.emb = CPA(3, self.in_planes, same=True)

        self.layer1 = self._make_layer(block, int(self.filters * 1), num_blocks[0], 1)
        self.layer2 = self._make_layer(block, int(self.filters * 2), num_blocks[1], 2)
        self.layer3 = self._make_layer(block, int(self.filters * 4), num_blocks[2], 2)
        self.layer4 = self._make_layer(block, int(self.filters * 8), num_blocks[3], 2)

        self.spa0 = SPA(img)
        self.spa1 = SPA(img)
        self.spa2 = SPA(int(img * 0.5))
        self.spa3 = SPA(int(img * 0.25))
        self.spa4 = SPA(int(img * 0.125))

        self.linear = nn.Linear(int(self.filters * 31), num_classes)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(int(self.filters * 31))

    def _make_layer(self, block, planes, num_blocks, stride):

        strides = [stride] + [1] * (num_blocks - 1)
        layers = []
        self.planes = planes
        planes = planes // num_blocks

        for i, stride in enumerate(strides):

            if i == 0 and stride == 1:
                layers.append(block(self.planes, self.planes, stride, same=True))
                strides.append(1)
                self.in_planes = self.planes

            elif i != 0 and stride == 1:
                layers.append(block(self.in_planes, planes, stride, cat=True))
                self.in_planes = self.in_planes + planes

            else:
                layers.append(block(self.in_planes, self.planes, stride))
                strides.append(1)
                self.in_planes = self.planes

        return nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x):

        out01 = self.root(x)
        out0 = self.emb(x, out01)

        out1 = self.layer1(out0)
        out2 = self.layer2(out1)
        out3 = self.layer3(out2)
        out4 = self.layer4(out3)

        out0_spa = self.spa0(out0)
        out1_spa = self.spa1(out1)
        out2_spa = self.spa2(out2)
        out3_spa = self.spa3(out3)
        out4_spa = self.spa4(out4)

        out0_gap = F.avg_pool2d(out0, out0.size()[2:])
        out1_gap = F.avg_pool2d(out1, out1.size()[2:])
        out2_gap = F.avg_pool2d(out2, out2.size()[2:])
        out3_gap = F.avg_pool2d(out3, out3.size()[2:])
        out4_gap = F.avg_pool2d(out4, out4.size()[2:])

        out0 = out0_gap + out0_spa
        out1 = out1_gap + out1_spa
        out2 = out2_gap + out2_spa
        out3 = out3_gap + out3_spa
        out4 = out4_gap + out4_spa

        out0 = F.layer_norm(out0, out0.size()[1:])
        out1 = F.layer_norm(out1, out1.size()[1:])
        out2 = F.layer_norm(out2, out2.size()[1:])
        out3 = F.layer_norm(out3, out3.size()[1:])
        out4 = F.layer_norm(out4, out4.size()[1:])

        out = torch.cat([out4, out3, out2, out1, out0], 1)

        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.bn(out)  # please exclude when using the test function
        out = self.linear(out)

        return out


def UPANets(f, c=100, block=1, img=32):
    return upanets(upa_block, [int(4 * block), int(4 * block), int(4 * block), int(4 * block)], f, num_classes=c,
                   img=img)


class upa_block(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_planes, planes, stride=1, cat=False, same=False, w=2, l=2):

        super(upa_block, self).__init__()

        self.cat = cat
        self.stride = stride
        self.planes = planes
        self.same = same
        self.cnn = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_planes, int(planes * w), kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(int(planes * w)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(int(planes * w), planes, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(planes),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        if l == 1:
            w = 1
            self.cnn = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(in_planes, int(planes * w), kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(int(planes * w)),
                nn.ReLU(),
            )

        self.att = CPA(in_planes, planes, stride, same=same)

    def forward(self, x):

        out = self.cnn(x)
        out = self.att(x, out)

        if self.cat == True:
            out = torch.cat([x, out], 1)

        return out


class CPA(nn.Module):
    '''Channel Pixel Attention'''

    #      *same=False:
    #       This scenario can be easily embedded after any CNNs, if size is same.
    #        x (OG) ---------------
    #        |                    |
    #        sc_x (from CNNs)     CPA(x)
    #        |                    |
    #        out + <---------------
    #
    #      *same=True:
    #       This can be embedded after the CNNs where the size are different.
    #        x (OG) ---------------
    #        |                    |
    #        sc_x (from CNNs)     |
    #        |                    CPA(x)
    #        CPA(sc_x)            |
    #        |                    |
    #        out + <---------------
    #
    #      *sc_x=False
    #       This operation can be seen a channel embedding with CPA
    #       EX: x (3, 32, 32) => (16, 32, 32)
    #        x (OG)
    #        |
    #        CPA(x)
    #        |
    #        out

    def __init__(self, in_dim, dim, stride=1, same=False, sc_x=True):

        super(CPA, self).__init__()

        self.dim = dim
        self.stride = stride
        self.same = same
        self.sc_x = sc_x

        self.cp_ffc = nn.Linear(in_dim, dim)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(dim)

        if self.stride == 2 or self.same == True:
            if sc_x == True:
                self.cp_ffc_sc = nn.Linear(in_dim, dim)
                self.bn_sc = nn.BatchNorm2d(dim)

            if self.stride == 2:
                self.avgpool = nn.AvgPool2d(2)

    def forward(self, x, sc_x):

        _, c, w, h = x.shape
        out = rearrange(x, 'b c w h -> b w h c', c=c, w=w, h=h)
        out = self.cp_ffc(out)
        out = rearrange(out, 'b w h c-> b c w h', c=self.dim, w=w, h=h)
        out = self.bn(out)

        if out.shape == sc_x.shape:
            if self.sc_x == True:
                out = sc_x + out
            out = F.layer_norm(out, out.size()[1:])

        else:
            out = F.layer_norm(out, out.size()[1:])
            if self.sc_x == True:
                x = sc_x

        if self.stride == 2 or self.same == True:
            if self.sc_x == True:
                _, c, w, h = x.shape
                x = rearrange(x, 'b c w h -> b w h c', c=c, w=w, h=h)
                x = self.cp_ffc_sc(x)
                x = rearrange(x, 'b w h c-> b c w h', c=self.dim, w=w, h=h)
                x = self.bn_sc(x)
                out = out + x

            if self.same == True:
                return out

            out = self.avgpool(out)

        return out


class SPA(nn.Module):
    '''Spatial Pixel Attention'''

    def __init__(self, img, out=1):
        super(SPA, self).__init__()

        self.sp_ffc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(img ** 2, out ** 2)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        _, c, w, h = x.shape
        x = rearrange(x, 'b c w h -> b c (w h)', c=c, w=w, h=h)
        x = self.sp_ffc(x)
        _, c, l = x.shape
        out = rearrange(x, 'b c (w h) -> b c w h', c=c, w=int(l ** 0.5), h=int(l ** 0.5))

        return out


class PUGD(torch.optim.Optimizer):

    def __init__(self, params, base_optimizer, **kwargs):

        defaults = dict(**kwargs)
        super(PUGD, self).__init__(params, defaults)

        self.base_optimizer = base_optimizer(self.param_groups, **kwargs)
        self.param_groups = self.base_optimizer.param_groups
        self.wd = self.param_groups[0]['weight_decay']
        self.mom = self.param_groups[0]['momentum']

    @torch.no_grad()
    def step(self, closure=None):
        assert closure is not None, 'There should be a closure'

        closure = torch.enable_grad()(closure)
        self.first_step()
        closure()
        self.second_step(zero_grad=True)

    @torch.no_grad()
    def xp_step(self, zero_grad=True):
        '''UGD = NGD-FW in Tensor'''
        grad_norm = self._grad_norm()

        for group in self.param_groups:

            for i, p in enumerate(group["params"]):
                if p.grad is None: continue

                p.grad = p.grad / (grad_norm + 1e-12)

        self.base_optimizer.step()

        if zero_grad: self.zero_grad()

    @torch.no_grad()
    def first_step(self):

        abs_grad_norm = self._abs_grad_norm()
        for group in self.param_groups:

            for i, p in enumerate(group["params"]):
                if p.grad is None: continue

                self.state[i]["e_w"] = torch.abs(p) * p.grad / (abs_grad_norm + 1e-12)
                p.add_(self.state[i]["e_w"])

    @torch.no_grad()
    def second_step(self, zero_grad=False):

        grad_norm = self._grad_norm()
        for group in self.param_groups:

            for i, p in enumerate(group["params"]):
                if p.grad is None: continue

                p.sub_(self.state[i]["e_w"])
                p.grad = p.grad / (grad_norm + 1e-12)

        self.base_optimizer.step()

        if zero_grad: self.zero_grad()

        return grad_norm.cpu()

    def _grad_norm(self):
        shared_device = self.param_groups[0]["params"][0].device
        norm = torch.norm(
            torch.stack([
                p.grad.norm(p=2).to(shared_device)
                for group in self.param_groups for p in group["params"]
                if p.grad is not None
            ]),
            p=2
        )
        return norm

    def _abs_grad_norm(self):
        shared_device = self.param_groups[0]["params"][0].device
        norm = torch.norm(
            torch.stack([
                (torch.abs(p) * p.grad).norm(p=2).to(shared_device)
                for group in self.param_groups for p in group["params"]
                if p.grad is not None
            ]),
            p=2
        )
        return norm

import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

from tqdm import tqdm



transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomCrop(32, padding=4),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
    ])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=64,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
# print(len(trainloader))
testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root='./data', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=64,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

classes = (
    'apple', 'aquarium_fish', 'baby', 'bear', 'beaver', 'bed', 'bee', 'beetle',
    'bicycle', 'bottle', 'bowl', 'boy', 'bridge', 'bus', 'butterfly', 'camel',
    'can', 'castle', 'caterpillar', 'cattle', 'chair', 'chimpanzee', 'clock',
    'cloud', 'cockroach', 'couch', 'cra', 'crocodile', 'cup', 'dinosaur',
    'dolphin', 'elephant', 'flatfish', 'forest', 'fox', 'girl', 'hamster',
    'house', 'kangaroo', 'keyboard', 'lamp', 'lawn_mower', 'leopard',
    'lion', 'lizard', 'lobster', 'man', 'maple_tree', 'motorcycle', 'mountain',
    'mouse', 'mushroom', 'oak_tree', 'orange', 'orchid', 'otter', 'palm_tree',
    'pear', 'pickup_truck', 'pine_tree', 'plain', 'plate', 'poppy', 'porcupine',
    'possum', 'rabbit', 'raccoon', 'ray', 'road', 'rocket', 'rose', 'sea',
    'seal', 'shark', 'shrew', 'skunk', 'skyscraper', 'snail', 'snake', 'spider',
    'squirrel', 'streetcar', 'sunflower', 'sweet_pepper', 'table', 'tank',
    'telephone', 'television', 'tiger', 'tractor', 'train', 'trout', 'tulip',
    'wardrobe', 'whale', 'willow_tree', 'wolf', 'woman', 'worm'
)


# 3*32*32
class Net2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net2, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 160)

        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(160,100)
        self.drop = nn.Dropout(0.5)


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.drop(x)
        # fully connect
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.drop(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)

        return x


class Net1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net1, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
             nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=5,padding=2),
             nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
             nn.ReLU(),
        )
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
             nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=5, padding=2),  
             nn.BatchNorm2d(32),  
             nn.ReLU(),
        )
        self.layer3 = nn.Sequential(
             nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=5, padding=2),  
             nn.BatchNorm2d(64),  
             nn.ReLU(),

        )
        self.layer4 =nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1),  
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),  
            nn.ReLU(),
        )
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 8 * 8, 100)
         
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = self.pool(self.layer2(out))
        out = self.pool(self.layer3(out))
        out = self.layer4(out)
        out = out.reshape(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.fc1(out)
        return out


if __name__ == '__main__':
    

    dataiter = iter(trainloader)  
    images, labels = next(dataiter)#




    net = UPANets(16,100,1,32)
    mode  = 'closure'

    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    print(device)

    net.to(device)

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()


    optimizer = PUGD(net.parameters(),
                     optim.SGD,
                     lr=0.001,
                     momentum=0.9,
                     weight_decay=5e-4,
                     )

    correct = 0
    total = 0

    for epoch in tqdm(range(100)): 
        running_loss = 0.0
        for i, data in tqdm(enumerate(trainloader, 0)):  

            inputs, labels = data

            inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()


            if mode == 'closure':

                def closure():

                    outputs = net(inputs)
                    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
                    loss.backward()


                outputs = net(inputs)
                loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step(closure)

            else:

                outputs = net(inputs)
                loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.first_step()

                outputs = net(inputs)
                loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.second_step(zero_grad=True)


            # print statistics
            running_loss += loss.item()
            if i % 2000 == 1999:  # i=1999,即print every 2000 mini-batches
                print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                      (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
                running_loss = 0.0
        if epoch % 20 == 0:
            with torch.no_grad():
                for data in testloader:
                    images, labels = data
                    images = images.cuda()
                    labels = labels.cuda()
                    images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
                    outputs = net(images)
                    _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                    total += labels.size(0)
                    correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

            print('Accuracy of the network on the 10000 test images: %d %%' % (
                    100 * correct / total))  #

    print('Finished Training')
    torch.save(net, 'complete_model.pth')

    correct = 0
    total = 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for data in testloader:
            images, labels = data
            images = images.cuda()
            labels = labels.cuda()
            images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
            outputs = net(images)
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

    print('Accuracy of the network on the 10000 test images: %d %%' % (
            100 * correct / total))  #


    torch.save(net, 'complete_model.pth')

After searching, I found that the issue might be related to mounting the Google Cloud disk, so I also placed the dataset in the 'content' directory,not the Google Cloud disk. At the same time, I adjusted the 'num_workers' parameter, but it still seems not as fast as expected.Does any know why this happened?

I tried the T4GPU too, the A100 is even slower than T4 GPU

I've got the reason, the batch size is too small. After I changed it to 1024, it was much faster than before. Hope this could help someone else.

That was going to be my first guess, low batch size, but in the end this has been asked and answered several times in the site, so this question is not really useful to anyone.

I've got the reason, the batch size is too small. After I changed it to 1024, it was much faster than before. Hope this could help someone else.
